# refactoring my own JsonArray after fetching data

Tags: android, arrays

here is my JsonArray which I want to make changes in -

```
[  
   {  
      "email":"orit@hero-apps.io",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"Orit Malki",
      "videoCounter":31,
      "winningCounter":8
   },
   {  
      "email":"1mdtalent@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"1MD Talent",
      "videoCounter":14,
      "winningCounter":2
   },
   {  
      "email":"kobi.shasha@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "videoCounter":13,
      "winningCounter":2
   },
   {  
      "email":"royjohnfriedman@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"roy friedman",
      "videoCounter":12,
      "winningCounter":3
   },
   {  
      "email":"ekaterina.lando@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"Ekaterina Lando",
      "videoCounter":7,
      "winningCounter":1
   },
   {  
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"oritheroapps",
      "videoCounter":5,
      "winningCounter":1
   },
   {  
      "email":"info@hero-apps.io",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"Hero Apps",
      "videoCounter":5,
      "winningCounter":3
   },
   {  
      "email":"xiaomiheroapps@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"xiaomi Heroapps",
      "videoCounter":4,
      "winningCounter":0
   },
   {  
      "email":"benkl15@gmail.com",
      "imageUrl":"***",
      "name":"Alon Shlider",
      "videoCounter":3,
      "winningCounter":0
   },

   "Mon Sep 02 13:48:42 GMT+03:00 2019"
]
```

I want to refactor my json array to be in the following format -

```
[
  "lastUpdate": {time},
  "data" : {//all of that data here}
]
```

after that I want to upload it to firebase data as a tree, so this is the reason I am asking this question. 
what would be the best way to do so? or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: firstly, your target JSON is invalid. You probably want `[{
  "lastUpdate": {time},
  "data" : {//all of that data here}}
]`

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to get the result you want -

```
private void getFullProfilesAsJson(ArrayList<YourObject> list) {
   JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   JsonArray data = new JsonArray();
   for (Object object : list) {
     JsonElement objectJson = gson.toJsonTree(object);
     data.add(objectJson);
   }
   String time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();
   JsonElement timeJson = gson.toJsonTree(time);
   retentionFeedJson.add("time", timeJson);
   retentionFeedJson.add("data", data);
   Timber.tag("jsonArray").d(retentionFeedJson.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this?

```
{"lastUpdate": {time},
  "data" : 
  [  
     {  
        "email":"orit@hero-apps.io",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"Orit Malki",
        "videoCounter":31,
        "winningCounter":8
     },
     {  
        "email":"1mdtalent@gmail.com",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"1MD Talent",
        "videoCounter":14,
        "winningCounter":2
     },
     {  
        "email":"kobi.shasha@gmail.com",
         "imageUrl":"***",
        "videoCounter":13,
        "winningCounter":2
     },
     {  
        "email":"royjohnfriedman@gmail.com",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"roy friedman",
        "videoCounter":12,
        "winningCounter":3
     },
     {  
        "email":"ekaterina.lando@gmail.com",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"Ekaterina Lando",
        "videoCounter":7,
        "winningCounter":1
     },
     {  
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"oritheroapps",
        "videoCounter":5,
        "winningCounter":1
     },
     {  
        "email":"info@hero-apps.io",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"Hero Apps",
        "videoCounter":5,
        "winningCounter":3
     },
     {  
        "email":"xiaomiheroapps@gmail.com",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"xiaomi Heroapps",
        "videoCounter":4,
        "winningCounter":0
     },
     {  
        "email":"benkl15@gmail.com",
        "imageUrl":"***",
        "name":"Alon Shlider",
        "videoCounter":3,
        "winningCounter":0
     }
  ]
}
```